# Wrong a:link tag being used (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, hyperlink, hover, visited

I use two different a:link/a:visited/a:hover tags.. But the links in .panel take over the a:link/a:visited from .footer and only gets a:hover from .panel right.

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel" id="tab4"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">Title</a> – Name</b>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel a:link, a:visited {
color:#333;
text-decoration:none;}

.panel a:hover {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;}

.footer a:link, a:visited {
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
opacity:0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */}

.footer a:hover {
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rules are a comma delimited list which are parsed by the browser right to left, top to bottom. When you do the following:

```
.panel a:link, a:visited{
    /*things*/
}

.footer a:link, a:visited {
    /*more things*/
}
```

The browser is saying:

"Ok, step one, for any `anchor` which is `visited`, do these rules. Then for any `anchor link` with a class of `panel`, do these same rules."

"On to step two, for any `anchor` which is `visited`, do these second rules {over writing your step one}, and for anything with the `class` of `footer`, do these second rules again."

So, make sure you have enough [CSS specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) to correctly target what you're looking to target.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `a:visited` twice, and the latter overwrites the values of the first.

```
.panel a:link, .panel a:visited {
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.footer a:link, .footer a:visited {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

This is probably what you are looking for. You can specify comma-delimited targets, but each one must by fully specified. Otherwise it would read like:

```
.footer a:link {
    <declarations>
}
a:visited {
    <declarations>
}
```